# Conditional case_sensitive validation in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have one model validation like below

```
validates :value, presence: true, allow_blank: false, uniqueness: { scope: [:account_id, :provider] }
```

I want to add one more condition of case_sensitive inside uniqueness like below

```
validates :value, presence: true, allow_blank: false, uniqueness: { scope: [:account_id, :provider], case_sensitive: :is_email? }

def is_email?
  provider != email
end
```

In short, it should not validate case_sensitive when email provider is not email, But currently, it's not working it is expecting true or false only not any method or any conditions.

How can I achieve this in rails? I already wrote custom validation because it was not working.

#### UPDATE

if I add another validation like below

```
validates_uniqueness_of :value, case_sensitive: false, if: -> { provider == 'email' }
```

It's giving me same error for twice `:value=>["has already been taken", "has already been taken"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the specific case of `case_sensitive`, the value passed to the option will always be compared against its *truthy* value.

As you can see in the class [`UniquenessValidator`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f33d52c95217212cbacc8d5e44b5a8e3cdc6f5b3/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb#L65), when the relation is built, it uses the options passed to check if the value of `case_sensitive` is truthy (not false nor nil), if so, it takes the `elsif` branch of the condition:

```
def build_relation(klass, attribute, value)
  ...
    if !options.key?(:case_sensitive) || bind.nil?
      klass.connection.default_uniqueness_comparison(attr, bind, klass)
    elsif options[:case_sensitive] # <--------------------------------- sadly, this returns true for :is_email?
      klass.connection.case_sensitive_comparison(attr, bind)
    else
      # will use SQL LOWER function before comparison, unless it detects a case insensitive collation
      klass.connection.case_insensitive_comparison(attr, bind)
    end
  ...
end
```

As you're passing the method name `is_email?` to `case_sensitive`, which is in fact a symbol, the condition takes that branch.

tl;dr;. You must always use `true` or `false` with `case_sensitive`.

Comment: Needless to say, you might want to re-think the way you're validating the uniqueness of new records, as this way is well-known to have a _hard performance_.

Comment: Thanks for the answer with a deep explanation. Yes, I know it will create a performance issue. Therefore, I will downcase the value before validation only and remove the case-sensitive option from uniqueness.

Comment: Although, I think rails should provide the options for conditional validation of case_sensitive. :D

Comment: Nice! Yes, I think so, knowing that that behavior is available in other parts of ActiveRecord and isn't available for `case_sensitive` is pretty confusing.